# requestFeature() must be called before adding content and it is called before in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I have a dialog like this

```
val buyDialog = Dialog(activity)
buyDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) //the stacktrace points here

        buyDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_buy_items)
        buyDialog.setTitle("Buy Items")
        buyDialog.setCancelable(false)
        buyDialog.window!!.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        val buy_items_cancel = buyDialog.buy_items_cancel


        showSoftKeyboard(buy_items_root, false)
        showProgress(buy_items_progress, false)

        buy_items_cancel.setOnClickListener {
            buyDialog.cancel()
            buyDialog.dismiss()
        }

        buyDialog.show()
```

This is working fine for the first time. So when I cancel the dialog by clicking on the cancel button and then again open this dialog I get the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.pckg.packer, PID: 27676
    android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:343)
```

I am calling this dialog from another AlertDialog like this

```
val builder = activity?.let { AlertDialog.Builder(it) }

            builder?.setTitle("Buy Items")
            builder?.setMessage("Do you want to buy available items?")

            builder?.setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, _ ->

                showBuyItemsDialog()

            }

            builder?.setNegativeButton("No") { dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder!!.create()

            alertDialog.show()
```

The error is pointing at the `buyDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong with your code. Are you sure this is whole code you shared ! something is not missing

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for two different cases:

1. In your code, `buyDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` won't work if you're using your activity as a Dialog. Extend `Activity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` and it should solve the problem.
2. If you're using `AppCompat`, it's necessary to call `requestFeature()` before `super.onCreate()`.